# How to pass a variable and instantiate a new api request from my NavBar.vue component file to my News.vue views file?

Tags: vue.js

I'm making an API request from https://newsapi.org/ and am able to do so with the created() method upon initiation. I have a component named Navbar.vue that includes buttons I'd like to use, upon click, to make a new api request and pass in a news source variable for the api request (e.g. 'cnn', 'fox-news'). Even though I've registered my News.vue in my Navbar.vue component, it doesn't appear I can use the created method to begin another instantiation. Here's a screen recording as well: https://drive.google.com/file/d/173x9PxLs5S2pWMYcHuXon0CQfoLwXNMT/view

I've tried calling NewsVue.created(source)

Top-Headlines/src/Components/Navbar.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light" variant="success">
        <b-container>
            <b-navbar-brand href="#">Top Headlines</b-navbar-brand>
            <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
            <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
             <b-button-group>
                <b-button variant="danger" v-on:click="getNews('cnn')">CNN</b-button>
                <b-button variant="info" v-on:click="getNews('espn')">ESPN</b-button>
                <b-button variant="warning" v-on:click="getNews('nbc-news')">NBC News</b-button>
            </b-button-group>   
            </b-collapse>
          </b-container>
      </b-navbar>
    </div>  
</template>
<script>
// import News from '../views/News';
import NewsVue from '../views/News.vue';
export default {
    // components: {
    //     NewsVue,
    // },
    data() {
        return {
            meal: ''
        }
    },
  methods: {
    getNews(source) {
        console.log(NewsVue);
        NewsVue.created(source);
    }
  }
}
```

Top-Headlines/src/views/News.vue:

```
    <template>
  <div class="articles-container">
    <template v-for="article in headlines">
      <div :key="article.publishedAt" class="article-container">
        <div class="article-source">
          <a v-bind:href="article.url">
            <h5>{{ article.title }}</h5>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
"use strict";

export default {
  name: "news",
  data() {
    return {
      headlines: [],
      search: "",
      newsSource: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getTopHeadlines(newsSource) {
      console.log(newsSource);
      let url = '';
      if (newsSource !== "" && newsSource !== undefined) {
        url =
          "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?" +
          "pageSize=10&" +
          "sources="+newsSource+"&" +
          "apiKey=ab07dee4fb7e4f198621ab4da0b1e5e9";
      } else {
        url =
          "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?" +
          "country=us&" +
          "pageSize=10&" +
          "apiKey=ab07dee4fb7e4f198621ab4da0b1e5e9";
      }
      var req = new Request(url);
      fetch(req)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          this.headlines = json.articles;
        });
    }
  },
  created(newsSource) {
    this.getTopHeadlines(newsSource);
  }
};
</script>
```

I expect the page to reload with news source filtered headlines.

Error messages:
"TypeError: this.getTopHeadlines is not a function
    at Object.created (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-"

Answer (score 1):

`created` is normaly called by the system and has `this` set to the component.  It seems you are trying to call it directly. You can either set `this` yourself by using `apply`, or by simply passing it in.

EITHER WAY, DON'T NAME THE FUNCTION `CREATED`, as it is reserved  for the Vue lifecycle.

```
NewsVue.created2(source, NewsVue);
```

To call a function `created2` and set the `this` context.

```
NewsVue.created2.call(NewsVue, source);
// or
NewsVue.created2.apply(NewsVue, [source]);
```

Either way, the function created2 will be invoked with `this` set to `NewsVue` and 1 parameter `source`.

Comment: Steven, thanks for that assistance. I'm having issues using the apply method. Could you show me how you'd use it?

Comment: Thanks @StevenSpungin, still having issues properly passing in my source parameter. Here's how my Navbar component method looks:  methods: {
    getNews(source) {
      console.log(NewsVue);
      NewsVue.created2.call(NewsVue, source);
    }
  }                                                                                                                   and here's my NewsVue.vue created2(): created2(newsSource) {
    getTopHeadlines(newsSource);
  }

Comment: I added another solution that is a bit more 'vue' oriented.  If that does not work, the issue is the context from your fetch callback.  First things first though, let me know if the watcher works.

Answer (score 0):

Use a watcher function, then set the data from the watcher.

BTW, NewsView should take newsSource as a property, and I don't even see that component in your template... Perhaps that's the root of your issue.  You need something like `<NewsView :newsSource='newsSource'/>` in the template.  Then move newsSource to props, and make the watcher immediate.

```
export default {
  name: "news",
  data() {
    return {
      headlines: [],
      search: "",
      newsSource: ""
    };
  },
  watch: {
    newsSource(value) {
      const newsSource = value;
      console.log(newsSource);
      let url = '';
      if (newsSource !== "" && newsSource !== undefined) {
        url =
          "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?" +
          "pageSize=10&" +
          "sources=" + newsSource + "&" +
          "apiKey=ab07dee4fb7e4f198621ab4da0b1e5e9";
      } else {
        url =
          "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?" +
          "country=us&" +
          "pageSize=10&" +
          "apiKey=ab07dee4fb7e4f198621ab4da0b1e5e9";
      }
      var req = new Request(url);
      fetch(req)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          this.headlines = json.articles;
        });
    }
  },
};
```